Error No se pudo obtener el archivo python del backend google colab
Presento el siguiente error al intentar abrir archivo python llamado "_apu.py" de mi google Drive en google Colab:
Error
No se pudo obtener el archivo _apu.py del backend.
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute')
    at g.refresh (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/b975a0c32eb2cd1821902aeadd1622b8/external_binary_l10n__es_419.js:4428:115)
    at g.setReadOnly (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/b975a0c32eb2cd1821902aeadd1622b8/external_binary_l10n__es_419.js:4427:251)
    at xa.program_ (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/b975a0c32eb2cd1821902aeadd1622b8/external_binary_l10n__es_419.js:7750:468)
    at za (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/b975a0c32eb2cd1821902aeadd1622b8/external_binary_l10n__es_419.js:16:57)
    at xa.next_ (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/b975a0c32eb2cd1821902aeadd1622b8/external_binary_l10n__es_419.js:14:195)
    at kaa.next (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/b975a0c32eb2cd1821902aeadd1622b8/external_binary_l10n__es_419.js:17:48)
    at b (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/b975a0c32eb2cd1821902aeadd1622b8/external_binary_l10n__es_419.js:17:309)

Hasta ahora he notado que sucede cuando intento programar desde dispositivos android con tamaño de pantalla pequeño. Por ejemplo, desde mi tablet de 14" no sucede el error, pero tengo un teléfono plegable con 2 pantallas y desde la pantalla externa (tamaño pequeño) sale el mismo error pero si abro la pantalla interna (tamaño grande) no sucede error.
Ahora estoy desde un teléfono de pantalla normal y nuevamente sucede el error.
¿Alguna sugerencia? Me gustaría poder escribir, así sea poco de código, desde cualquier sitio que me encuentre.
Gracias.

¿Cómo se llama el archivo? ¿Lleva o no una barra baja al principio?

Se llama _apu.py, el nombre creo no afecta ya que se ha abierto normal desde otros dispositivos. Es el mensaje de error que no he podido resolver.
